# What's a good alternative to an Arduino Nano that can be used with Neopixels?

Tags: arduino-uno, neopixel

I'm doing an arduino project in school which requires neopixels, but the Arduino's too big. Is there an arduino I can use that's compatible with neopixels? Thanks!

Comment: How big it too big? Have you looked at Arduino Micro or Pro Mini. Even the DigiSpark runs NeoPixels

Comment: The Teensy (3.2 and better) [OctoWS2811 LED Library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OctoWS2811.html) is really interesting too.

Answer (score 2):

**ESP8266** mini is the best and cheaper alternative 2$5 on [Ali express](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ESP8266-ESP-12-USB-WeMos-D1-Mini-WIFI-Development-Board-D1-Mini-NodeMCU-Lua-IOT-Board/32788532951.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.34.73c15e69VXCTQ6&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_5722815_10342_10343_10340_5722915_10341_5722615_10697_10696_10084_10083_10618_10305_10304_10307_10306_10302_5722715_10059_10184_10534_308_100031_10103_441_10624_10623_10622_5722515_10621_10620,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&algo_expid=56ee0025-711a-4836-b371-13b4603c10fb-5&algo_pvid=56ee0025-711a-4836-b371-13b4603c10fb&priceBeautifyAB=0). Then 100% compatible with arduino toolchain/IDE + very impressive community/github library!

Answer (score 1):

There are Arduino ProMinis (they have the same specs as the nano) also there's an arduino digispark tiny 85 (they have lower specs than the nano) and at the end there are just microcontrollers that can be soldered on a PCB that is enough small for you (they have a big range of specs)
Here is a comparison to the nano [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an Arduino, however there is an STM32 which you can program almost identical to an Arduino (using the Arduino IDE). It's the STM32F103C8T6.

[image]